# How to get process or port Network bandwidth usage in linux

Tags: linux, networking, process, port

I want to get network bandwidth usage for each process. I have found a lot of information about this, such as iftop, [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/), [linux process explorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/procexp/)...
But all of them get process brandwidth usage by capture packet(libpcap), by my test in linux it consume a lot of cpu(%10-%15) and the speed of flow is 11MByte/s. If I can get flow rate for each port I can solve this questions because I hava get the table about process port used. So I want to know is there any other way to get port flow without capture packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Linux doesn't offer an alternative interface to pcap for calculating network usage. `/proc/<PID>/stat(us)` contains various process information but nothing about network access, only the total I/O usage including disk access.

Similarly, to know the port you have to read at least the IP header. Hence I assume it is not possible to speed this up significantly, because analyzing all packets in user space will always be slow. A kernel module for this task seems to be the only option.

Comment: You means I must write patch for kernel? But my users can not allow me to do this

Comment: You don't have to, of course. But you asked about a fast solution.

Answer (score 5):

**The below answer isn't actually correct. The file doesn't contain per-process information**

`/proc/[pid]/net/netstat` contains the bandwidth information per process,where pid is the process id.

```
cat /proc/"pid"/net/netstat | \
 awk '(f==0) {name=$1; i=2; while ( i<=NF) {n[i] = $i; i++ }; f=1; next} \
(f==1){ i=2; while ( i<=NF){ printf "%s%s = %d\n", name, n[i], $i; i++}; f=0} '
```

Reference:
https://sa-chernomor.livejournal.com/9858.html

Comment: Hi @BusyTraveller, this is actually not true. Although the netstat proc file is under the <pid> folder, it is actually still system level netstat metrics, at least based on my testing on Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel version of 4.15.0-46-generic.

Comment: Actually a good answer to this question could be found in this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224201/what-is-proc-pid-net-dev

Comment: Just carrying the statement here: "/proc/net contains statistics about the general network, while /proc/<pid>/net/dev contains statistics about network from the process' point of view."

Comment: If all the process you have are in the same network namespace, then all the counters of those processes are the same.