# How to calculate how much network IO a python script is using?

Tags: python, networking

Let's consider the following file `script.py` that makes a dummy request:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://example.com")
```

I can estimate how much network bandwidth I have used by the size of `response`.

What if the script has become complex and involves the use of multiple libraries? It gathers information from multiple websites, processes it, and outputs the results as a json file in the same directory.

In this scenario, how can the network bandwidth usage of the script be determined for each run? Would I have to manually go through the codebase and "add up" all the requests by hand? That does not seem feasible.

Comment: what about iftop?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm talking about measuring it precisely and programmatically. Preferably by a simple way of adding a header or wrapper around the script.

Comment: The size of the response is not the actual network bandwidth you consume. This depends heavily on the network protocol in use and it's likely you cannot measure it in-process precisely because, e.g., the tcp stack is implemented in kernel. 
If you use Linux these links may help:
- https://superuser.com/questions/1034518/how-to-calculate-network-traffic-by-process-on-linux
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219550/how-to-get-process-or-port-network-bandwidth-usage-in-linux/49314308

Comment: `atop` can also monitor network traffic if the required kernel module is installed: https://www.atoptool.nl/netatop.php

BPF could help too: http://www.brendangregg.com/bpf-performance-tools-book.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution code I ended up using:

```py
import requests

total_sent_length = 0
total_recv_length = 0

get_sent_length   = 0
get_recv_length   = 0

post_sent_length  = 0
post_recv_length  = 0

old_request_method_get  = requests.get
old_request_method_post = requests.post

def format_size(bytes, suffix='B'):
    """
    return bytes in a human readable format
    """
    for unit in ['', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z']:
        if abs(bytes) < 1024.0:
            return '%3.1f%s%s' % (bytes, unit, suffix)
        bytes /= 1024.0

    return '%.1f%s%s' % (bytes, 'Y', suffix)

def rlen(response):
    """
    approximate request size sent to server
    """
    len_of_meth = len(response.request.method)
    len_of_addr = len(response.request.url)
    len_of_head = len('\r\n'.join('{}{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in response.request.headers.items()))
    len_of_body = len(response.request.body if response.request.body else [])

    return len_of_meth + len_of_addr + len_of_head + len_of_body

def patched_get(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    delegate functionality and record stats
    """
    global total_sent_length
    global total_recv_length

    global get_sent_length
    global get_recv_length

    response = old_request_method_get(*args, **kwargs)

    total_sent_length += rlen(response)
    total_recv_length += len(response.content)

    get_sent_length += rlen(response)
    get_recv_length += len(response.content)

    return response

def patched_post(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    delegate functionality and record stats
    """
    global total_sent_length
    global total_recv_length

    global post_sent_length
    global post_recv_length

    response = old_request_method_post(*args, **kwargs)

    total_sent_length += rlen(response)
    total_recv_length += len(response.content)

    post_sent_length += rlen(response)
    post_recv_length += len(response.content)

    return response

requests.get  = patched_get
requests.post = patched_post

print('total_sent_length', format_size(total_sent_length))
print('total_recv_length', format_size(total_recv_length))

resp1 = requests.get('http://www.example.com/')
resp2 = requests.get('http://www.example.com/')

print('total_sent_length', format_size(total_sent_length))
print('total_recv_length', format_size(total_recv_length))
```

And here would be the sample results of a run:

```py
total_sent_length 0.0B
total_recv_length 0.0B
total_sent_length 242.0B
total_recv_length 2.5KB
```